# ALE configuration in SAP

Tags: idoc

I would like to know if it is possible to use the save client to configure the ALE for IDoc.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you're trying to do? From your question I can't even begin to guess...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use same client for sending and receiving IDocs. (Hint: LSMW can perform data conversion using Idocs)